# how can i remove or hide the text of tabs in TabBar .NET MAUI?

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

For Android Platform:

I want to use icons only in the bottom TabBar in .NET MAUI,
So I have to either remove the title or hide it,
If i leave the title empty without text, it retains its space, so the icon does not fill all the space

[image: .NET MAUI TabBar]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the custom shell renderer to remove the title's view in the bottom tab bar.

Create the custom renderer class in the /Platforms/Android:

```
public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        public MyShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
        {
            return new MyShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker();
        }
    }
    public class MyShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker : IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
        {
        }

        public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, IShellAppearanceElement appearance)
        {
            bottomView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityUnlabeled;
            // this line will hide the space of the title
        }
    }
```

And use the Renderer in the MauiProgram.cs:

```
builder

                  .UseMauiApp<App>()
                  .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                  {
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                  })
                  .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                  {
#if ANDROID
                        handlers.AddHandler(typeof(Shell), typeof(Platforms.Android.MyShellRenderer));
#endif
                  })
                  ;
```

And in the AppShell.xaml:

```
    <TabBar>
        <Tab
            Icon="main.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab
        Icon="page1.png">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage1}"/>
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
```

Comment: is this only for android ? how about ios ? i have not tried it for ios since my apple developer enroll is still not approved.

Comment: iOS don't have to do this. It will auto fit if you don't have the text. @khalil

Comment: i just tried on my IOS 17 phone, it doesnt auto fit. which method should i override for ios ? seems like the method is different from android.

Comment: Sorry for that I'm not good at ios, you can try to post a new question. And you can refer to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371589/how-to-remove-the-tabss-titlestext-when-using-a-shell-structure-with-bottom-t). @khalil

Comment: i found the problem already. it is because i didnt set to Title="". I only did <Tab Icon="home2.png">